# Issues with datasets when custom SLD loaded into geoserver

Tags: qgis, geoserver, symbology, sld

I have created my SLD's in [QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63627/issues-with-exporting-qgis-symbology-to-sld-when-symbology-uses-zoom-levels) and want to use them in Geoserver. I have imported and validated them without any problems

but when I try to view the data using Layer Preview --> OpenLayers-->Go it tries to download the data rather than let me view it. With the default symbology it works fine.

Is there something fundamental that I have to change in the SLD from Geoserver for it to work?

One of the simple and 2 complex SLD's are below (roads at different zoom levels)

Roads - Simple

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>Roads_GHD_20121121</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>Roads_GHD_20121121</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>GHD Roads</se:Name>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>250000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.4</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-dasharray">5 2</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Roads - Complex

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
                       xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
                       xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
                       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>Road with border</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>Road with border</Title>

            <!-- Local Roads -->
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>State_cont</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>Y</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>0</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>1787</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#CDAA66</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">12</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>State_cont</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>Y</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>0</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>1787</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">11</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>road_name2</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </Label>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <LinePlacement/>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                        <Halo>
                            <Radius>
                                <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                            </Radius>
                            <Fill>
                                <CssParameter name="fill">
                                    <ogc:Literal>#FFFFFF</ogc:Literal>
                                </CssParameter>
                                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
                                    <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                                </CssParameter>
                            </Fill>
                        </Halo>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">30</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">800</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="repeat">1000</VendorOption>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>

            <!-- Local Roads 1787 - 3573-->
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>State_cont</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>Y</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>1787</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>3573</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#CDAA66</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">7</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>State_cont</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>Y</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>1787</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>3573</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">6</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>road_name2</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </Label>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <LinePlacement/>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                        <Halo>
                            <Radius>
                                <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                            </Radius>
                            <Fill>
                                <CssParameter name="fill">
                                    <ogc:Literal>#FFFFFF</ogc:Literal>
                                </CssParameter>
                                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
                                    <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                                </CssParameter>
                            </Fill>
                        </Halo>                        
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">30</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">800</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="repeat">1000</VendorOption>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>

            <!-- Local Roads 3573 - 28573-->
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>State_cont</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>Y</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>3573</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>28573</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#CDAA66</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">4</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <ogc:Filter>
```

Points Complex with SVG files.

```
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>State_cont</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>Y</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>3573</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>28573</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>road_name2</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </Label>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <LinePlacement/>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                        <Halo>
                            <Radius>
                                <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                            </Radius>
                            <Fill>
                                <CssParameter name="fill">
                                    <ogc:Literal>#FFFFFF</ogc:Literal>
                                </CssParameter>
                                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
                                    <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                                </CssParameter>
                            </Fill>
                        </Halo>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">30</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">800</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="repeat">1000</VendorOption>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>

            <!-- Local Roads 28573 - 114287 -->
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>State_cont</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>Y</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>28573</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>114287</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#D7C29E</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>

            <!-- State Roads - 0 - 1787 -->
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>State_cont</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>state</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>0</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>1787</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#CDAA66</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">13</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>State_cont</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>state</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>0</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>1787</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#FFFF00</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">12</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>road_name2</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </Label>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <LinePlacement/>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                        <Halo>
                            <Radius>
                                <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                            </Radius>
                            <Fill>
                                <CssParameter name="fill">
                                    <ogc:Literal>#FFFF00</ogc:Literal>
                                </CssParameter>
                                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
                                    <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                                </CssParameter>
                            </Fill>
                        </Halo>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">30</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">800</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="repeat">1000</VendorOption>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>

            <!-- State Roads - 1787 - 3572 -->
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>State_cont</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>state</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>1787</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>3573</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#CDAA66</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">7</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>State_cont</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>state</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>1787</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>3573</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#FFFF00</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">6</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>road_name2</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </Label>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <LinePlacement/>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                        <Halo>
                            <Radius>
                                <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                            </Radius>
                            <Fill>
                                <CssParameter name="fill">
                                    <ogc:Literal>#FFFF00</ogc:Literal>
                                </CssParameter>
                                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
                                    <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                                </CssParameter>
                            </Fill>
                        </Halo>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>                        
                        <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">30</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">800</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="repeat">1000</VendorOption>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>

            <!-- State Roads - 3572 - infinity -->
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>State_cont</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>state</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>3573</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#CDAA66</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>State_cont</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>state</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>3573</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#FFFF00</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">4</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>road_name2</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </Label>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <LinePlacement/>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                        <Halo>
                            <Radius>
                                <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                            </Radius>
                            <Fill>
                                <CssParameter name="fill">
                                    <ogc:Literal>#FFFF00</ogc:Literal>
                                </CssParameter>
                                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
                                    <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                                </CssParameter>
                            </Fill>
                        </Halo>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>                        
                        <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">30</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">800</VendorOption>
                        <VendorOption name="repeat">1000</VendorOption>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: that isn't data it is trying to download it's the error message - look at the file or check the log and add the actual error to your question

Comment: You also have to know that Geoserver does not currently support completely the SLD produced by QGIS... There is a version mismatch here that you have to take into account

Comment: @iant Thanks...I did not know that this file was an error report. That will help in resolving the issue.

Comment: @iant -I just looked at the file and for some reason one of the attributes was renamed. Once I corrected this GS shows the correct symbology in the Layers--Properties--publishing--default style column but when you view the data, you can't see anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS produces SLD 1.1 while Geoserver only seems to support SLD 1.0 currently. The Geoserver blog indicates that they are working on it though, e.g. http://blog.geoserver.org/2013/02/26/geoserver-2-3-rc1-released/

Comment: -thanks. Can we downgrade QGIS to produce SLD 1.0. I had a look at http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRendererV2.html#ae429cdcf8219b1f8f8c3c02a67871ead but it's not clear and I haven't implemented qgis python before.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in OpenLayers (wasn't using GeoServer) with an SLD 1.1.0 file from QGIS for a GeoJSON layer, but found a sloppy workaround via some find-and-replace magic in the SLD file:

1. Changed beginning of file (xml prologue is it called??) to match 1.0 standards:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <sld:StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
   xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">`
2. Changed all instances of `SvgParameter` to `CssParameter` (credit to the suggestion at the end of [this post](http://cartaro.org/blog/14-how-use-qgis-great-looking-symbols-cartaro)).
3. Changed all instances of `<se:whatever>stuff</se:whatever>` to `<sld:whatever>stuff</sld:whatever>` (this may have been just a QGIS feature, I am not sure).

Like I said, not pretty, but it allowed me to adapt a 1.1.0 SLD file exported from QGIS and then parse it in OpenLayers.