# QGIS SLD in GeoServer

Tags: qgis, geoserver

I rendert a beautiful with QGIS based on OSM data.
Now I want to publish it via GeoServer.
I am new to GeoServer but as far as I it does not accept SLD files created by QGIS.

My GeoServer cannot validate my code.

Does someone has a clue how to change the style so that GeoServer recognizes it?

The SLD content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
<NamedLayer>
<se:Name>bahn</se:Name>
<UserStyle>
  <se:Name>bahn</se:Name>
  <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name>Railway</se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title>Railway</se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:Not>
          <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
            <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
          </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
        </ogc:Not>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:MinScaleDenominator>1</se:MinScaleDenominator>
      <se:MaxScaleDenominator>10000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
      <se:LineSymbolizer>
        <se:Stroke>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#e4e4e4</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Stroke>
      </se:LineSymbolizer>
      <se:LineSymbolizer>
        <se:Stroke>
          <se:GraphicStroke>
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:Mark>
                <se:WellKnownName>line</se:WellKnownName>
                <se:Fill>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#e4e4e4</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Fill>
                <se:Stroke>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#e4e4e4</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>
              </se:Mark>
              <se:Size>1</se:Size>
            </se:Graphic>
            <se:Gap>
              <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
                <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Filter>
            </se:Gap>
          </se:GraphicStroke>
        </se:Stroke>
      </se:LineSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
  </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues with datasets when custom SLD loaded into geoserver](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63758/issues-with-datasets-when-custom-sld-loaded-into-geoserver)

Comment: I've read that before and tried to do the changes. But without success. Therefore I posted this question.

Comment: I would perhaps create a style that reminds your QGIS style with uDig and compare the two SLDs.

Comment: thanks. But that's what I want to avoid. I've got lots of layers with that problem. Anybody knows if this will be integrated in future versions of GeoServer?

Comment: could you mention what the error is?

Comment: I meant to use uDig for helping you to find where the problems is really. You would not like to avoid that I guess. But @iant gave you better advice.

Comment: I didn´t check this on my own, but sld in newer versions of geoserver are compatible with QGis sld

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - I pasted the SLD you supplied in to GeoServer - first it helpfully points out that you are missing the closing tags for

```
  </NamedLayer>
  </StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

at the end.

Once the XML is complete it complains about

```
line 46: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ogc:Filter'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":expression}' is expected.
line 47: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ogc:Literal'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":spatialOps, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":comparisonOps, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":logicOps, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":_Id}' is expected.
```

So there is a problem at line 46 - it seems that it was expecting an expression (Literal, PropertyName etc) in the se:Gap element and you have a Filter (which is badly formed). If you delete the Filter and the /Filter elements everything validates.

However you will notice that the style is not showing up in the preview - this is because line is not a Well Known Name for a mark (see this [list](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/pointsymbols.html#standard-symbols)) so replacing it with shape://vertline fixes all your issues.

This looks like the SLD is invalid as generated so you may want to file a bug report with the QGIS folks.

Comment: I've filed the bug report but you might want to add how you created the sld (http://hub.qgis.org/issues/11202)

Answer (score 1):

Here´s what worked out for me:
Basically it´s just 3 steps, using the "search and replace" tool:

1- i replaced the first line with one from an existing geoserver sld:

2- Also copy the first lines raplacing the "****" with your own

```
<sld:NamedLayer>
         <sld:Name>****** </sld:Name>
               <sld:UserStyle>
                    <sld:Name>*****</sld:Name>
                    <sld:Title>******</sld:Title>
                    <sld:Abstract>******</sld:Abstract>
                      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
```

and do the same with the closings

```
                       </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                </sld:UserStyle>
        </sld:NamedLayer>
```

3- Use the search and replace tool: replace  `<se:` and  `</se:` with `<sld:` and `</sld:` respectivly. And replace  `SvgParameter` with `CssParameter`

Sorry if i don´t use correct vocabulary, i´m not so much into coding, neather into english language. Please someone improve my answer.

A co-worker made a script to do the steps before automatically with RStudio and made it even simpler for me.