# geoserverRestPublisher not publishing sld correcltly

Tags: java, geoserver-rest-api, geoserver-manager

Hi I'am using geoserver manager plugin for publishing my shapefiles and styles through my web application, but the problem is that the style is not publishing correctly.

this is how it should be (uploaded by geoserver locally) :

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>Altitude</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>Altitude</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>400</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>400</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>Altitude</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>400</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#d33845</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>1000</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>1000</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>Altitude</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>1000</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#56e44c</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>2000</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>2000</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>Altitude</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>2000</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#d06ad9</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>4000</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>4000</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>Altitude</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>4000</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#4de8de</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>4500</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>4500</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>Altitude</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>4500</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#eade32</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

but that is what I'm receiving (uploaded by geoserver-manager)

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>Altitude</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>Altitude</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>400</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>Altitude</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>400</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill/>
            <sld:Stroke/>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>1000</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>Altitude</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>1000</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill/>
            <sld:Stroke/>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>2000</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>Altitude</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>2000</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill/>
            <sld:Stroke/>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>4000</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>Altitude</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>4000</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill/>
            <sld:Stroke/>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>4500</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>Altitude</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>4500</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill/>
            <sld:Stroke/>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

this is the code line I'm using for the publishing

```
publisher.publishStyle("workspace_name", sldFile, "filename");
```

I think that the problem is that the geoserver-manger automatically convert my style body (xld version 1.1.0 ) to (xld version 1.0.0)
I tried to force geoserver to use version 1.1.0 `GeoServerRESTPublisher.Format.SLD_1_1_0.getContentType()` but with no success

this is the body of `publishStyle` function

```
StringBuilder sUrl = new StringBuilder(buildPostUrl(null, name));
String contentType = GeoServerRESTPublisher.Format.SLD.getContentType();
        if(!this.checkSLD10Version(sldBody)){
            contentType = GeoServerRESTPublisher.Format.SLD_1_1_0.getContentType();
        }
 
LOGGER.debug("POSTing new style " + name + " to " + sUrl + " using version: " + contentType);
String result = HTTPUtils.post(sUrl.toString(), sldBody, contentType, gsuser, gspass);
```

Comment: Your assumption seems correct - can you add the code where you set the format to the POST?

Comment: @IanTurton I added the body of my function which contain the POST method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading a couple of posts I found that there are some changes I have to make to do the conversion from SE to SLD :

1- `<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1.0">`
to `<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">`

2- `StyledLayerDescriptor` to `sld:StyledLayerDescriptor`

3- `UserStyle` to `sld:UserStyle`

4- `NamedLayer` to `sld:NamedLayer`

5- `SvgParameter` to `CssParameter`

6- `se:` to `sld:`

7- REMOVE `<se:Description>` and `</se:Description>`

And then I created a function that automate the job

```
    public static String SeToSLD(String line, int index) throws Exception {
        
        if(index == 1 )
            line = "<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns=\"http://www.opengis.net/sld\" xmlns:sld=\"http://www.opengis.net/sld\" xmlns:gml=\"http://www.opengis.net/gml\" xmlns:ogc=\"http://www.opengis.net/ogc\" version=\"1.0.0\">";
        else {
            line = line.replaceAll("StyledLayerDescriptor", "sld:StyledLayerDescriptor");
            line = line.replaceAll("UserStyle", "sld:UserStyle");
            line = line.replaceAll("NamedLayer", "sld:NamedLayer");
            line = line.replaceAll("SvgParameter", "CssParameter");
            line = line.replaceAll("<se:Description>", "");
            line = line.replaceAll("</se:Description>", "");
            line = line.replaceAll("se:", "sld:");
        }
        return line;
    }
...
String body = "";
            int index = 0;
            List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("PathToFile");
            for (String line : allLines) {
                body += SeToSLD(line, index) + "\n";
                index++;
            }
            
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sldFile);
            writer.write(body);
            writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the `Content-type` MIME types to be set in the HTTP PUT/POST requests for the different versions of the SLD standard are not the same:

- SLD 1.0 requires `application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml`
- SLD 1.1 / SE 1.1 requires `application/vnd.ogc.se+xml`

as stated in the GeoServer's documentation here:
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/styles.html#rest-api-styles-post-put